# Normality of residuals of ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, arima, normality-assumption

Is the normality of data important if I have more than 100 observations? I have a time series data which include 143 monthly observations. I used ARIMA to fit the data due to the absence of seasonality. Although the data are monthly from Jan. 2008 up to Nov. 2019, the time series graph is not showing a clear seasonality. ARIMA model (2,0,0) is selected, the ARIMA parameters were significant at alpha=0.05, with no auto correlation in the residuals. By checking the normality I found the it is less than 0.05 using Anderson-Darling method. I want to use the $t$-test for checking if the mean of the residuals is constant as well as the variance test.

My question is that since the number of observations is 143, can I discard the normality of the residuals and proceed with the mentioned tests? Actually I tried many distributions but the residuals are not following any of them. At the same time I don't want to transform the data to avoid any changes in the data.

Comment: why don't  you post your actual data . your model with coefficients , your residuals and we can take a look

Comment: Upload your time series plot, acf and pacf plot